# Cordova - disable background mode or multi-tasking in Android

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a way to disable multi-tasking in Android? In iOS, you can set `UIApplicationExitOnSuspend` to `YES` in `info.plist` will do the job. Is there an equivalent setting I can set for Android to achieve the same thing? Basically I want to kill the app the moment it goes into background, and start fresh when they come back.

I am using Cordova.